# How do I get the first element in a row returning True on a given function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

Say I have a table with two columns: name and age, and that the table's rows are ordered by age.

I need a function to find the name of the youngest person who is at least 50 years old.

**Example**

For this list:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Nordom | 3 |
| Annah | 19 |
| Ignus | 56 |
| Morte | 72 |

We'd get "Ignus".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said age column is sorted so can try below formula.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A2:A5,B2:B5>=50),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, As far as I know if you use index and filter, you should also sort the range before you take first index.  So I'd rather suggest: =INDEX(Sort(FILTER(A2:A5,B2:B5>=50)),1)

Comment: Ups... rather: =INDEX(Sort(FILTER(A2:B5,B2:B5>=50),2,1),1,1) - first filter values, then sort both columns by second column, then take only first column of the first row.

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski OP already mentioned that `Age` column is sorted. So, no need `SORT()` function. If `Age` column is not sorted then you need `SORT()` function.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(A:B; "select A where B >= 50 limit 1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=query(B3:C,"select B,C where C > "&E3&"  order by C limit 1")
```

[image]

If you want just Ingus with no headers and age, you can do:

```
=query(B3:C,"select B where C > "&E3&"  order by C limit 1",0)
```